# Keyboard freezes for a few minutes after plugging in peripherals

Tags: keyboard, freeze, plasma, peripherals

I have an odd problem I cannot make heads or tails of.

My machine is  running Ubuntu 22.04 with KDE Plasma desktop 5.27.10.

Whenever I plug a peripheral device (keyboard, mouse, microphone), the keyboard freezes for a minute or longer. To make matters more confusing, this freeze has two phases.

At first, keystrokes are registered by xev, but are otherwise not registered by any program. The cursor moves and clicks, whether it is controlled by the mouse or using the keyboard (I have a programmable keyboard on which I set keys to that function).

During the second phase, keys are not registered by xev anymore, but the cursor moves still moves (with the keyboard and mouse). However, the mouse keys are reversed - left becomes right and right becomes left. This is not arbitrary craziness; I have a left handed mouse and "Left handed mode" —which switches the two keys— toggled on. I suspect that what happens is that this non-default setting becomes transiently non-applied.

On either phase, if I switch to an alternative terminal (I'm not sure what's the right term; the console that opens when one fires ctrl-alt-F(2-12)), keyboard keys are registered normally, e.g. I can log in and interact with the console.

This freeze is rather long. I never measured it, it seems to be somewhat variable, and is mostly at least a minute long. When it's over, it's seems that at least some of the keystrokes that had been made are registered; at the very least, if I had tried to alt-tab during it, there will be a window switch at the end of the freeze, but it doesn't seem like all of those former key strokes are input in a cascade at that moment.

This was the situation since I ever got the computer (new, a year ago). It is the case with two different keyboard models.

Any help would be appreciated.

edit:
per @waltinator suggestion, I'm appending the logs of `journalctl`. I've removed the date and the name of the computer to fit the long lines better.
This and one of the comments made me realize that this freezing doesn't happen when I connect (by usb) external harddrives.

Disconnecting the keyboard (ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I). Disconnected at the very beginning of these and reconnected 2 second laters. Keyboard resumed working at about 21:15:50:

```
21:14:31 kernel: usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 5
21:14:31 acpid[1155]: input device has been disconnected, fd 15
21:14:31 acpid[1155]: input device has been disconnected, fd 24
21:14:31 acpid[1155]: input device has been disconnected, fd 25
21:14:31 acpid[1155]: input device has been disconnected, fd 26
21:14:33 kernel: usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
21:14:34 kernel: usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=3297, idProduct=1969, bcdDevice= 0.01
21:14:34 kernel: usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
21:14:34 kernel: usb 3-2: Product: Moonlander Mark I
21:14:34 kernel: usb 3-2: Manufacturer: ZSA Technology Labs
21:14:34 kernel: input: ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0d:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:3297:1969.0012/input/input40
21:14:34 kernel: hid-generic 0003:3297:1969.0012: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I] on usb-0000:0d:00.3-2/input0
21:14:34 kernel: hid-generic 0003:3297:1969.0013: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I] on usb-0000:0d:00.3-2/input1
21:14:34 kernel: input: ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0d:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.2/0003:3297:1969.0014/input/input41
21:14:34 kernel: hid-generic 0003:3297:1969.0014: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I] on usb-0000:0d:00.3-2/input2
21:14:34 kernel: input: ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0d:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.3/0003:3297:1969.0015/input/input42
21:14:34 mtp-probe[142405]: checking bus 3, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0d:00.3/usb3/3-2"
21:14:34 mtp-probe[142405]: bus: 3, device: 6 was not an MTP device
21:14:34 kernel: input: ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0d:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.3/0003:3297:1969.0015/input/input43
21:14:34 kernel: input: ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0d:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.3/0003:3297:1969.0015/input/input44
21:14:34 kernel: hid-generic 0003:3297:1969.0015: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I] on usb-0000:0d:00.3-2/input3
21:14:34 systemd-logind[1189]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event2 (ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I)
21:14:34 systemd-logind[1189]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event6 (ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I Keyboard)
21:14:34 systemd-logind[1189]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event5 (ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I Consumer Control)
21:14:34 systemd-logind[1189]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event4 (ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I System Control)
21:14:34 mtp-probe[142439]: checking bus 3, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0d:00.3/usb3/3-2"
21:14:34 mtp-probe[142439]: bus: 3, device: 6 was not an MTP device
21:15:01 CRON[145959]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
21:15:01 CRON[145960]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
21:15:01 CRON[145959]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
21:15:32 kcminit[146022]: Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_mouse.so"
21:15:32 kcminit[146022]: Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_touchpad.so"
21:15:32 kcminit[146022]: kcm_touchpad: Using X11 backend
```

Here I disconnceted my mic (Kingston HyperX Quadcast, connected by usb). Keyboard resumed functionality at about 21:20:12:

```
21:18:57 plasmashell[3349]: org.kde.plasma.pulseaudio: No object for name "alsa_input.usb-Kingston_HyperX_Quadcast_4110-00.3.analog-stereo"
21:18:57 plasmashell[3349]: file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.volume/contents/ui/ListItemBase.qml:119: TypeError: Value is undefined and could not be converted to an object
21:18:57 plasmashell[3349]: org.kde.plasma.pulseaudio: No object for name "alsa_output.usb-Kingston_HyperX_Quadcast_4110-00.3.analog-stereo"
21:18:57 plasmashell[3349]: org.kde.plasma.pulseaudio: No object for name "alsa_input.usb-Kingston_HyperX_Quadcast_4110-00.3.analog-stereo"
21:18:57 plasmashell[3349]: file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.volume/contents/ui/ListItemBase.qml:119: TypeError: Value is undefined and could not be converted to an object
21:18:57 acpid[1155]: input device has been disconnected, fd 9
21:19:01 kernel: usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
21:19:01 kernel: usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=16df, bcdDevice= 1.00
21:19:01 kernel: usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
21:19:01 kernel: usb 3-3: Product: HyperX Quadcast
21:19:01 kernel: usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Kingston
21:19:01 kernel: usb 3-3: SerialNumber: 4110
21:19:01 kernel: input: Kingston HyperX Quadcast Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0d:00.3/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.3/0003:0951:16DF.0016/input/input45
21:19:01 mtp-probe[146608]: checking bus 3, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0d:00.3/usb3/3-3"
21:19:01 mtp-probe[146608]: bus: 3, device: 7 was not an MTP device
21:19:01 kernel: hid-generic 0003:0951:16DF.0016: input,hiddev2,hidraw6: USB HID v1.00 Device [Kingston HyperX Quadcast] on usb-0000:0d:00.3-3/input3
21:19:01 systemd[2871]: Reached target Sound Card.
21:19:01 mtp-probe[146629]: checking bus 3, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0d:00.3/usb3/3-3"
21:19:01 mtp-probe[146629]: bus: 3, device: 7 was not an MTP device
21:19:01 wireplumber[2881]: The decibel volume range for element 'Speaker' (-4000 dB - -900 dB) has negative maximum. Disabling the decibel range.
21:19:01 wireplumber[2881]: The decibel volume range for element 'Speaker' (-4000 dB - -900 dB) has negative maximum. Disabling the decibel range.
21:19:01 wireplumber[2881]: The decibel volume range for element 'Speaker' (-4000 dB - -900 dB) has negative maximum. Disabling the decibel range.
21:19:01 wireplumber[2881]: The decibel volume range for element 'Speaker' (-4000 dB - -900 dB) has negative maximum. Disabling the decibel range.
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I have a similar problem with Ubuntu 23.10.  In my case, my mouse suddenly lags when I plug in a certain number of USB devices.  I gave up trouble-shooting it (since I don't think I know enough how); I rarely have to plug in the number of devices to cause this problem to occur.  Personally, I'm hoping a future kernel upgrade will fix this problem as it was fine with an older version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Does it happen with only USB hardware, only Bluetooth, or any hardware indiscriminately?

Comment: @Jos I don't often connect Bluetooth so I can't remember. It doesn't happen with KDE connect, I can say that. It happens with USB devices, though, you made me realize, it doesn't happen with (usb connected) external hardware. It also doesn't happen when I connect devices to the audio jack.

Answer (score 0):

Within 5 minutes of the event, the terminal command `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` will show system logs that cover the event. Read `man journalctl`. Each log message starts with a timestamp, the host that issued the log entry, the process name, the PID in `[]` of the issuer and a colon (`:`). Everything after the colon is a message from the programmer, intended to help the user understand the program's behavior. Read `man logger`.

You might be in need of swap space. Use `free` to see if you have any.

One uses swap space to control what happens when programs allocate all the real memory, and want more. After all releasable cache (some cached blocks are "in use", and cannot be freed) has been released, the system enters the Out-Of-Memory state. In the Out-Of-Memory condition, with swap, some task's memory is written to disk, freed for reuse, and later  returned to memory (swapped in) when the task runs. Without swap, the system may freeze,  the dreaded OOM-Killer (a pseudo process, hard-coded in the kernel) runs, and picks a process to KILL, in order to free memory. The OOM-Killer is known for inconvenient choices.

System hibernation requires a RAM-sized, contiguous swap area.

Read `man mkswap fallocate  filefrag swapon fstab`.

Comment: Thank you. Running `free` I get
`Swap:        8388604       64256     8324348` (total        used        free), so it doesn't seem the problem. As for `journalctl`, it seems like perhaps the `was not an MTP device` point to the culprit, but I'm not sure. I'm adding the logs to my original post.